# Angular: debounceTime for dynamically generated input type

Tags: angular, rxjs, viewchildren

I have a list of cards. The list of cards is dynamic and the data is injected with @Input. Each card has a "description" input.
The goal is that, when the 'description' input is updated (keyup), it automatically waits for 500ms (debounceTime) and then automatically emits the new value to parent component (that will dispatch the ngrx action).

Everything works perfectly but the "adding" of debounceTime. I tried to add the debounceTime using the viewChildren operator,fromEvent  and AfterViewInit but the queryList is "undefined" even if i'm calling it inside the afterViewInit method.
I expected the queryList is iterable as Angular documentation but it's not.
The number of cards is dynamic, so i cannot use a formControl for valueChanges() method.
Could you please indicate what am i missing?

```
export class ProductsDataComponent implements AfterViewInit{
  
  @ViewChildren('inputDesc', { read: ElementRef }) arrOfInputs!: QueryList<ElementRef>
  @Input() myborse!: IResource[];
  @Input() length!: number;
  @Input() pageSize!: number;
  @Input() pageSizeOptions!: number[];
  @Output() emitterBin: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() emitterUpdateBorsaTracking: EventEmitter<IProductCardUpdateTracking> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() emitterUpdateBorsaDescription: EventEmitter<IProductCardUpdateDescription> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() emitterPageChange: EventEmitter<PageEvent> = new EventEmitter();

  
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.arrOfInputs.forEach(input=>{
      fromEvent(input.nativeElement, 'keyup').pipe(
        debounceTime(500)
      )
      .subscribe(res => console.log('emitEvent to parent. This line is never triggered'));
    })
  }
 onChange=(id:string)=>{

  }
}
```

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-12 col-lg-3" *ngFor="let borsa of myborse">
        <div *ngIf="borsa!==undefined">
            <mat-card class="example-card">
                <mat-card-header>
                    ...
                </mat-card-header>
                <div>
                    <ngb-carousel #carousel>
                        ...
                    </ngb-carousel>
                </div>

                <mat-card-content>
                    <mat-form-field class="example-form-field" appearance="outline">
                        <input matInput type="text" #inputDesc id={{borsa._id}} value="{{borsa.description}}"
                            placeholder="Description"
                            (input)="onChange(borsa._id)"
                            >
                    </mat-form-field>
                </mat-card-content>
                <mat-card-actions>
                    ...
                </mat-card-actions>
            </mat-card>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<mat-paginator #paginator 
    ...
</mat-paginator>
```

Answer (score 0):

If everything works perfectly without `debounceTime`, it must be change detection issue. You can inject `ChnangeDetectorRef` an manually say angular to detect the changes.
If it won't help you can change approach to not react on each event directly and use `setTimeout` for delay 500ms

Comment: At the end i had to create a micro component <card> giving the card.description value.  Since each card has a input for the description, i created a form control in the card component (form control has already its valueChanges). Problem solved but i'm not sure if this is a solution or a workaround...

Comment: Noone of my suggestion helped? You say component with inputs solves it, so it really sounds like change detection issue. If your Angular is at least v17 you can try signals. Also `id={{borsa._id}} value="{{borsa.description}}` such syntaxis is not recomended by Angular. Use next: `[id]=borsa._id [value]="borsa.description`